# How to prevent Storyboard Segue from resetting UIViewController inside UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ios5, uipopovercontroller, storyboard

Here's my problem. With Storyboard's segue I am having a popover segue for a bar button. The UIViewController inside the UIPopoverController requires to load the data from a server. With Storyboards, everytime I close the popover the view is released so whenever the popover appears again it tries to load data again from server. I dont want this behavior. How can I prevent Storyboard from resetting the view controller inside popover controller? Something like what UITabBarController does. UITabBarController calls viewDidLoad for the first time and for the subsequent tab switches viewWillAppear is called.

Answer (score 4):

Segue is designed so. Every time you do segue - view will be loaded.
If you need to store it's data - you should store it outside popover and use this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"your segue identifier"])
    {
        //get popover
        ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        //Set popover data to vc here
    }
```

which calls before segue, and in this method set data to popover. 
If you will use it - don't forget to set Segue identifier in Interface Builder.

Comment: But this will add the extra complexity of loading data outside the view controller. The code for loading data which should ideally be in the view controller will now be in the popover parent controller. I worked around this issue by not using segues and always creating popover by hand. But I really want to be able to use Segue.

Comment: As I understand - segue always will be create new ViewController. Or don't use segue, or use segue knowing this.
But you can try to use custom segue, but I think nothing will change with that.

Comment: Custom Seque is not a choice, since anything that is maintained using Segue is released once its job is done. So the current solution seems to be not using Segues at all and just do it by hand the old way.